Unable to pass in switchboard randomness data
i want to upload switchboard randomness data,but i cant read the randomness_data.reveal_slot it's always 0

this is my code
Instruction
pub fn process_commit_randomness(ctx: Context<CommitRandomness>) -> Result<()> {
let clock = Clock::get()?;
let token_lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.token_lottery;
if ctx.accounts.payer.key() != token_lottery.authority {
    return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidAuthority.into());
}

let randomness_data =
    RandomnessAccountData::parse(ctx.accounts.randomness_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();

msg!(
    "Randomness revealed at slot: {}",
    randomness_data.reveal_slot
);
msg!("clock slot: {}", clock.slot);
if randomness_data.reveal_slot != clock.slot - 1 {
    return Err(ErrorCode::RandomnessAlreadyRevealed.into());
}

token_lottery.randomness_account = ctx.accounts.randomness_account.key();

Ok(())
}

test
 it("commit randomness", async () => {
const sbQueue = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
  "A43DyUGA7s8eXPxqEjJY6EBu1KKbNgfxF8h17VAHn13w"
);
const queueAccount = new sb.Queue(switchboardProgram, sbQueue);

try {
  await queueAccount.loadData();
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error:", error);
  process.exit(1);
}

const [randomness, createRandomnessIx] = await sb.Randomness.create(
  switchboardProgram,
  rngKp,
  sbQueue
);

const createRandomnessTx = await sb.asV0Tx({
  connection: provider.connection,
  ixs: [createRandomnessIx],
  payer: wallet.publicKey,
  signers: [wallet.payer, rngKp],
});

const createRandomnessTxHash = await provider.sendAndConfirm(
  createRandomnessTx
);
console.log("--------------------------------");
console.log("Create randomness transaction hash:", createRandomnessTxHash);


const sbCommitIx = await randomness.commitIx(sbQueue);

const commitRandomnessIx = await program.methods
  .commitRandomness()
  .accounts({
    randomnessAccount: randomness.pubkey,
  })
  .instruction();

const blockhashWithContext = await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const commitRandomnessTx = new anchor.web3.Transaction({
  feePayer: wallet.publicKey,
  blockhash: blockhashWithContext.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashWithContext.lastValidBlockHeight,
  })
  .add(commitRandomnessIx)
  .add(sbCommitIx);

const commitRandomnessTxHash = await provider.sendAndConfirm(
  commitRandomnessTx
);
console.log("--------------------------------");
console.log("Commit randomness transaction hash:", commitRandomnessTxHash);
});

